# C# StreamReader or String reads more characters than asked for

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I am having trouble understanding what the String.Substring method is doing. Here is my code (it is a vanilla VisualStudio C# console application with some code added by me):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace foo {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String pathToFile = "the-path-to-the-file";

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("encoding = " + streamReader.CurrentEncoding);

            String fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("encoding = " + streamReader.CurrentEncoding);

            String substring = fileContents.Substring(0, 35);
            Console.WriteLine("substring length = " + substring.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("substring = " + substring);

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            Console.WriteLine("encoding = " + streamReader.CurrentEncoding);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The file found at pathToFile contains:

> fromæ®²ç´ãƒ»ãƒ€ã‚¦ãƒ«ãƒ€ãƒ–ãƒ©.endxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

which in hex is :

```
00000000h: 66 72 6F 6D E6 AE B2 E7 90 B4 E3 83 BB E3 83 80 ; fromæ®²ç´ãƒ»ãƒ€
00000010h: E3 82 A6 E3 83 AB E3 83 80 E3 83 96 E3 83 A9 2E ; ã‚¦ãƒ«ãƒ€ãƒ–ãƒ©.
00000020h: 65 6E 64 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 ; endxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00000030h: 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 ; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The program outputs:

> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding
>
> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding
>
> substring length = 35
>
> substring = fromæ®²ç´ãƒ»ãƒ€ã‚¦ãƒ«ãƒ€ãƒ–ãƒ©.endxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Whereas I want it to output:

> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding
>
> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding
>
> substring length = 35
>
> substring = fromæ®²ç´ãƒ»ãƒ€ã‚¦ãƒ«ãƒ€ãƒ–ãƒ©.end
>
> encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding

So my question is why does `substring.Length` return 35 but `substring` seems to contain > 35 characters? Am I using `String.Substring` incorrectly? Or is it something to do with the `StreamReader`? Or something else?

Comment: are you sure that file is ut8 encoded?

Comment: Don't use strings to manipulate binary data.

Comment: Please take time to format your code nicely, but *don't* use the `>` to quote it all...

Comment: @Cory - please elaborate (note: I am not an expert in C#).

Comment: I should point out that the file contains a part of a larger file, and that larger file is supposed to be in utf8. Are you saying that the file is not utf8? I can't get my head around how utf8 encoding works, but those are definitely the bytes from the file in question.

Comment: What is the file used for?

Comment: It is a file full of text strings. If I open it in UltraEdit hex mode you see those same bytes you see above. It is supposed to be in utf8 encoding. I'm trying to read the text strings in so that I can use them as file names.

Comment: That does not look like text meant for reading. Is the file not for some other program?

Comment: Use StreamReader.Read Method (Char[], Int32, Int32) instead of readtoend. You are not reading strings. You are reading binary data.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. The characters `E6AEB2` converted to binary are `1110 0110 1010 1110 1011 0010`, which, according to wikipedia are the leading/continuation bytes of a utf8 encoded character. So I need to work out how to read in those bytes to a C# string as C# characters.

Comment: Yes, you can't just interchange bytes with characters.  A utf8 encoded character may be more than 1 byte in length.  Your question title is misleading because you aren't asking streamreader to read x number of characters, you read them all.

Comment: You should likely be using `new StreamReader(pathToFile,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)` to open the file rather than letting it guess.

Comment: The problem now is that the `StreamReader` won't read bytes. The `StreamReader.Read` method converts them to a `Char[]` (ie. to 16 bits again). I could use a different reader to read the stream but some of the files I need to read have both 16 bit unicode characters and 8/16/24 bit utf8 characters in them.

Comment: I just tried `new StreamReader(pathToFile,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)` and got the same result as before. I think it was already using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` according to the original output?

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader is reading correctly, Substring produces exactly 35 characters.

Point is that System.Console - creepy Microsoft product - is not able to display Unicode characters.

You can verify this by running the same code in the GUI-application. In MessageBox or in Label you will get the desired output.